# what is the difference between UNIQUE INDEX and UNIQUE KEY?

Tags: mysql

I have seen couple of sample tables one is with UNIQUE INDEX and other is with UNIQUE KEY.
what is the difference between two?? or both are same?

Comment: see : http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/218317

Comment: In MySQL the terms *key* and *index* tend to be used interchangeably, as pointed out in the post given by haim evgi.  In MS SQL, they can refer to different things: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/366186/is-the-sql-server-unique-key-also-an-index#answer-366200

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[CREATE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table.html)
KEY is normally a synonym for INDEX.

You can use them interchangeably as described in syntax page
[CONSTRAINT [symbol]] UNIQUE [INDEX|KEY]

Comment: No, the syntax page does not say that INDEX and KEY are interchangeable, but can be used as the next argument for the UNIQUE constraint.

Comment: Please be clearer about why KEY and INDEX can be used interchangeably. I found http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/218317 (from Haim Evgi's comment above) helpful.